# Knockout difference between template binding and control flow binding

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js

I have seen two approaches to use templates in knockout:

Using [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html):

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'templateName', foreach: tags}"></ul>
<script id="templateName" type="text/html">
    <li class="tagItem"><span data-bind="text: name"></span></li>
</script>
```

And [control flow binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html):

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: tags">
    <li class="tagItem"><span data-bind="text: name"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Both having the same ViewModel:

```
var viewModel = {
  tags : ko.observableArray([{name: 'tag1'}, {name: 'tag2'}])
}
```

As far as I see the result is the same, but the second one is

- shorter to write
- does not have this weird script tag
- is not fragmented into different places
- easier to understand

So what is the reason for the first case? (the only thing I see right now is to have it separated in some other file).

Comment: Code reuse is the main goal of the templates! What if you want to display tags the same way in two places. You don't copy paste the foreach with all its content but turn it to template binding move the common part into a template and just reference it from both places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the big plus of the first case is **resusability**.

Imagine you want to insert such a list in a handful of pages and they should look the same in all of them. Would you go the second way and copy paste this code over and over again? I don't think so. You would rather build the template in a seperate file and refer to it via `data-bind`.

Additionally you can dynamically hand over whatever array you like that shall be iterated when using `data-bind="template: {name: 'templateName', foreach: tags}"`, so a second plus should be **flexibility**.

In order to elaborate that point a little further think about the following example. Using simple binding without a template means you will have to write the HTML whereever necessary **plus** the JavaScript binding code:

```
var viewModel = {
  tags : ko.observableArray([{name: 'tag1'}, {name: 'tag2'}])
}
```

In the case of templates this is much easier as you only have to define which array to choose in the template:

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'templateName', foreach: tags}"></ul>
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'templateName', foreach: news}"></ul>
```

This would render two lists for different arrays. The advantage is that you save writing the JavaScript binding code as well as the repeated HTML. What I meant by flexibility is that we can use the same code for arrays that don't contain tags as well. The only constraint is that those arrays also contain objects that have the name-property.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating with some code, please?

`Additionally you can dynamically hand over whatever array you like that shall be iterated when using data-bind="template: {name: 'templateName', foreach: tags}", so a second plus should be flexibility.`